# How to install Wine or Winetricks and Virtualbox into Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox, wine

There are no other questions and answers that clearly explain how to install Wine or Winetricks and or Virtualbox into Ubuntu 16.04.

Unfortunately, Ubuntu 16.04 does not come with Winetricks and or Virtualbox already installed. Obviously it would save a lot of frustration if Ubuntu 16.04 did have them already installed.

I need Wine to operate my Internet connection. Currently I connect to the Internet via Windows 10 and can only download applications via Windows 10, copy to a CD then insert the CD into the Ubuntu environment. I'll need Virtualbox to operate other Windows based programs, so I need to learn how to install both applications.

I've downloaded Wine from http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Emulators/Wine-148.shtml#download then copied it to a CD, inserted into the Ubuntu environment, and it shows as "wine-1.9.9.tar.bz2" but I have no idea of what to do with it from there.

I've also downloaded Virtualbox from http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/VirtualBox.shtml#download then copied it to the same CD, inserted into the Ubuntu environment, and it shows as "VirtualBox-5.0.20-106931-Win.exe" but again I have no idea of what to do with it from there.

Can somebody explain in simple terms how do I install both applications into Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Just install the `winetricks` and `virtualbox` packages. They should be available in Ubuntu Software.

Comment: Why would you need Wine for the internet? Ubuntu can connect on its own. If you have a network driver problem, then ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Many of us are delighted that Ubuntu does not include wine and virtualbox by default.

Comment: winetricks and virtualbox are not available in Ubuntu Software.

Comment: The Internet needs to be paid for. I doubt Ubuntu can connect for free. The ISP I'm using is Windows based.

Comment: I think you need to add other software in the software and updates window.  I will post it in my answer.

Comment: It is extremely doubtful that you need Windows to connect to the internet regardless of what your ISP uses.  It is extremely likely that you are choosing a very poor approach to solving your basic problem, which is internet connectivity with Ubuntu 16.04  If you provided more information about why you think you can't connect in Ubuntu (instead of just saying your ISP uses Windows), you will probably get a much better solution.

Comment: Do not worry about what a ppa is.  Just get the software screen and check the boxes.  You will surely need internet.  Do you have wifi?  or telephone.?  Just click on the network icon in the panel.

Answer (score 4):

Do not listen to the other complex answers.
All of the files are available from the standard ubuntu repos.  There are no ppa's to add. These are standard Ubuntu programs. 
The software center does not work ( I have no idea why they shipped it).
That is why you cannot do anything.

However, you will need to checkmark all of the boxes in the software and updates applet:
[image]

Also it is good to go to the next tab and check off the sources is OtherSoftware for canonical partners.  This will give you skype and some other things.  (Hit the "Super button" or "windows" key and type "software" to get the screen above.

In a terminal session (CTRL+ALT+T). Simply type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

I think wine tricks will be there too.
You might want to install play on linux

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Be sure that when you install wine that you are online.  It will want to ask you about installing some stuff from microsoft.  Make sure you agree to the terms and then select the forward button.  Do not do anything until it installs completely because a popup window will come for the fonts.  You might miss it if you have many windows open.

You can find these in the app store (not so good) or through synaptic (recommended)

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

You do not need apt-get and can simply use sudo apt install  in 16.04 but I use the old way to help people because it works in all versions.

Comment: Bhikkhu Subhuti I can't "Simply type" if I don't know where to type. Please explain where to type those words?

Comment: You are a real newbie!  Ok.. load up terminal from the menu and then you can type all you want, but better to type the commands I said :)  Ignore ALL of the other answers, .you are way too new.  Your question was so simple that people assumed you had a complex problem.  Welcome to installing software on linux.

Comment: Bhikkhu Subhuti I am new to Ubuntu, I don't understand your terminology. Where are standard ubuntu repos? What are ppa's? What and where is a terminal session? I can't go online until I have an emulator to make the ISP connection work. I am online in my old Windows laptop. Where is the app store or synaptic? I'm very confused.

Comment: How do I load up terminal from the menu?

Comment: Bhikkhu Subhuti when I click on Ubuntu Software tab I get a window nothing like the one you have shown. At the top left it says Ubuntu Software, next line down in the middle are tabs "All" "Installed" "Updates", the next line is a text box where I've typed "wine" virtualbox" and other names, they all come up with "No Application Found".

Comment: I can't download from the Internet on the laptop with Ubuntu because it is not connected to the Internet. I can only download on my laptop with Windows. Benny (below) provided this link "Download Virtual Box directly from official website" which has downloaded into my Windows laptop. But I don't know what to do with it. I can copy it onto a CD then transfer it to the laptop with Ubuntu, but from there I'm lost.

Comment: Bhikkhu Subhuti maybe you need to download the latest Ubuntu 16.04 to see what I'm encountering. I've downloaded twice the 2nd from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: You definitely need the internet.  Create a wifi hotspot on your telephone and connect to the internet by clicking on the network icon.  You will see your hotspot (tether).  You can also just create a usb tether too on your smart phone.  Connection to the internet does not require windows.  This is ridiculous.  hit the super button (windows key) and type software and you should see "software and updates"  Do the same thing and type "term" and you should see something.  If not type  ctrl + alt+t .  You need to watch some Videos on youtube.  I also will update the answer.  Read again

Comment: read the title of my screen shot.  Find that app.  Hit the window's key or super key and type "software" and look for software and updates.

Answer (score 0):

**Install Wine 1.7.35 in Ubuntu:**

The official ppa is available to install Wine. Add the ppa and update the local repository, then install Wine.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7
```

After installation is completed, you can run Microsoft Windows based software in your Linux distribution.

**Installing VirtualBox From Precompiled Binaries:**

You find VirtualBox binaries and download them from here: http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads.
Then use the command line:

```
sudo su
```

Then install the dependencies:

```
apt-get install bcc iasl xsltproc xalan libxalan110-dev uuid-dev zlib1g-dev libidl-dev libsdl1.2-dev libxcursor-dev libqt3-headers libqt3-mt-dev libasound2-dev libstdc++5 linux-headers-`uname -r` build-essential
```

some

```
cd /tmp
wget http://www.virtualbox.org/download/1.3.8/VirtualBox_1.3.8_Ubuntu_edgy_i386.deb
```

After download  is finished you can start installation by typing:

```
dpkg -i VirtualBox_1.3.8_Ubuntu_edgy_i386.deb
```

You might get asked some confirmation questions:

1. Do you agree with the PUEL license terms? <-- Yes (just click  the letter "y" on the keyboard and enter)
2. Should the vboxdrv kernel module be compiled now? <-- Yes

I hope this helps and Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

how to install wine on ubuntu:
https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

installing a tar.bz2:
[How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

install virtualbox on ubuntu
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Installation
it might be just as simple as running a command in bash
**sudo apt install virtualbox-qt**

you need a linux version of virtualbox if you want to run this on ubuntu you have a "VirtualBox-5.0.20-106931-**Win**.**exe**" windows executable

why would you need wine for your internet connection? Could you elaborate? ubuntu is perfectly capable of connecting to the internet.

Comment: How do I run a command in bash?

Comment: Where do I get a linux version of virtualbox?

Comment: The ISP I'm using is Windows based so I need Wine to make it work and be able to connect to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

### VirtualBox

Download

- [Download VirtualBox for Linux](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

Install

- [How do I install a .deb file](https://askubuntu.com/a/841370/538619)

---

### Wine

- [Installing WineHQ packages](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks Benny, virtualbox has downloaded into my laptop with Windows. I can copy it onto a CD then transfer it to the laptop with Ubuntu, but from there I'm lost.